# getting No route matches [GET] "/show_house_search.38" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I defined a new method in my controller to show customized show page for my houses after one click on search results.

**houses_controller.rb**

```
 def show_house_search
    @house = House.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @house.photos
  end
```

then I declared the routes in **routes.rb**

```
  get '/show_house_search/:id', to: 'houses#show_house_search', as:'show_house_search'
```

and when I am using it  as

```
<%= link_to show_house_search_path(house.id),id:'house_search' do %>
<li id="house-<%= house.id %>">
  <span class="user" style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: 200;text-decoration: dotted;"><%= house.title %></span>
  <span class="content"style="font-size: 15px;color: purple;font-weight: 600;">Price <i class="fa fa-inr"></i><%= house.price %></span>
  <span class="badge"><%= house.house_structure%></span>  </span>
  <span class="badge"><%= house.location%></span>  </span>
</li>
  <%end%>
```

clicking on this link is showing me this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/show_house_search.38"
```

while I also searched for a route for my request using **rails routes**

```
    show_house_search_path  GET     /show_house_search/:id(.:format) houses#show_house_search
```

Comment: Why are you not using a member action? any specific reason

Comment: i m using it already..  but now I wanted additional show method for showing my search results thats why i created customized show method.

Answer (score 1):

Please change menthod

```
show_house_search_path(house.id)
```

to

```
show_house_search_path(id: house.id).
```

As shown in routes.rb, path is `/show_house_search/:id(.:format)`, it seems that `id` is considered as `:format` hence appending to routes as( .id).

Comment: This is not needed, as the op commented but for some reason deleted. He had forgotten to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
<%= link_to show_house_search_path(id: house.id) ,id:'house_search' do %>
```

Comment: This is not needed, as the op commented but for some reason deleted. He had forgotten to restart the server.